# Cutting a Straight Section of Moulding into Wedge Shapes that Form an Ellipse when Assembled

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections

I would like to cut a straight piece of moulding into wedged shapes that, when assembled, will form an ellipse.  The goal is to wrap this moulding around the perimeter of an elliptical arch that is installed between two porch columns. I need to know the miter saw angles for cutting each wedge.

I can measure distances *a* and *b* on the ellipse (see illustration below) where the width is *2a* and the height is *2b*.  I would like to cut moulding wedges where the outside edge is a fixed width *w*.  There will be wedges 1 through *i* cut from the straight piece.  The moulding has height *h*.

How can I generate a spreadsheet giving the cut angles for wedge *i*?

[image: Moulding Wedges]

[image: Example of straight moulding and its application to the elliptical arch]

Comment: This may be a better fit for engineering stackexchange.

Comment: @Dale: this question deals with finding angles between the focal radii of an ellipse at discrete points where a line is tangent to the ellipse.  The illustration is meant to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have to apologize for not giving a mathematical answer, but are you quite sure that those things are ellipses, or do they just look like ellipses? Do you have to do a lot of them? If so, are they all exactly the same? As a practicing woodworker I would never trust a "theoretical prediction", even if it was easy to do (which it would be) because errors in measurement and execution are cumulative. I would cut two "wedges" with square ends, offer them up and measure the gap.

SUPPLEMENT
Then I guess you could define a set of points on the ellipse by $$x_i=a\cos(\theta_i),y_i=b\sin(\theta_i)$$
Then the angle that each wedge makes with the horizontal is $$\arctan[(y_{i+1}-y_i)/(x_{i+1}-x_{i})]$$
and from these angles you easily get the angles between the wedges and hence the cut angles. The length of each wedge comes from Pythagoras.

The remaining question is how to choose the angles $\theta_i$. The wedges can be longer closer to the center of the arch, but just how much longer probably doesn't matter. A simple choice is to make the angles $\theta_i$ equally spaced and this somewhat mimics planetary motion in which equal arcs are swept out in equal times. Otherwise this is a good use for a drawing board, since the only criterion is what looks good.

As a practical suggestion, on the job I would work in from each end and fit the last
wedge by offering it up and marking it, so as to cancel any errors in the cutting. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, these are ellipses that were routed using an elliptic trammel.  The rendering includes a springline, where the ellipse begins 2 inches above a vertical section.

Comment: thank you for the help.  I was able to produce the spreadsheet following this approach.  The angles can be determined by setting the cut width *w* to useful widths.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a spreadsheet that models an elliptical quadrant as 500 points to determine miter cut angles.  The calculations follow the approach suggested above.  The "Cut Angle" calculated would be half for each butting wedge.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDt99-U0SVsVBH06s2_CoYVDNkrfQeZ6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Glad that I could help!